# How to print numbers with $ symbol in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm working with Perl at the moment and I just don't know how to print the number $34.6666666 as $34.67 when I execute it.

I was able to do it using this script:

```
printf "%0.2f\n", 34.6666666;
```

It gives me the output of 34.67, but I'm trying to incorporate the $ sign in my output, which I don't how to do.  Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also, don't use floating point for money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put an escaped $ in your format string

```
printf "\$%0.2f\n", 34.6666666;
```